How to resolve collision between wedge and AABB or capsule
I have a 3D world where all of my terrain uses AABBs as collision volumes (think minecraft, but not strictly cubes):

I want to add wedge pieces as a terrain option. They'll have various slopes and be able to face all 8 cardinal and ordinal directions. Here's an example of the south-facing wedges:

Questions:

Is there anything bad about using wedges as collision volumes? Maybe some more standard way that slopes are handled in tile-based 3D worlds?
How should I define these volumes in code?
How can I detect and resolve collision between my player entity and these volumes?
How can I stop the entity from being able to walk up steep slopes?

It can be assumed that the player entity will use an AABB for collision. The bottom center point can be used for colliding with the top face of the wedge, but the whole AABB should be used for colliding with the sides. A capsule can be used instead if that's easier.

Will these wedges always be placed with the full square bottom face flat against the floor, so entities collide with them from the sides/top? Or do you need them as overhangs or in arbitrary orientations (not strictly as ramps)?

Colliding with them from the bottom will be possible, they may be placed above the ground.
